# How can I uninstall Mac AppStore Apps?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, mac-app-store

How can I uninstall MacAppStore Apps?

Comment: I'm not a Mac guy but I was under the impression for normal apps you just put them in the trash.  Is that not the same with ones from the Appstore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drag them into the trash, and empty it.

If you want to be really thorough, look in `~/Library/Preferences`, `~/Library/Application Support` and occasionally `~/Documents` for files and folders bearing the application's name - these will be settings or cache files - and delete them.

Comment: Such a shame you can't uninstall them neatly like on the iPhone

Comment: Dragging them to the trash isn't neat?

Comment: @TheLearner Being forced to delete all preferences and data isn't that neat either.